# Determining NLog is running asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, nlog

I was wanting to check that NLog was running asynchronously. I set up a Async wrapper executed some code in a loop, paused the execution and looked in the Threads debug window and I could see a NLog thread.

I then put my loop on a separate thread and wanted to ensure that NLog was also on another thread but when looking in the Threads debug window I could not see anything.

Is there a way to determine that NLog is definitely running on a separate thread?

Comment: The source is available on the website. I would be more inclined to just look at the code instead of trying to draw conclusions from a debug session in VS.

Comment: Tried that but whether or not I use async wrapper or not the same code is called and I can't see any threads or tasks being used